# placement new unique pointer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr

It's one of my first posts. I hope it contains the correct, minimal information. Please let me know if I omitted anything.

I'm trying to use placement new to increase the efficiency of the following chunk of code (I want to reduce the number of memory allocation calls since the `number_of_actions` variable is large (> 500k)).

First, I am using two classes whose relationship can be summarized as:

```
class txn {
public:
  int i;
  txn(): i(0) {};
};

class ActionClass {
private:
  txn* t;
public:
  ActionClass(txn* t): t(t) {};
  ~ActionClass() { delete t; }
};
```

The code I was using originally to create an array of pointers to objects:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction>> allocate_actions(unsigned int number_of_actions) {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction>> res;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < number_of_actions; i++) {
    // construct the action
    std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction> act = std::make_unique<ActionClass>(new TestTxn());

    res.push_back(std::move(act));
  }
  return res;
}
```

Code after changing to use placement new:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction>> allocate_actions(unsigned int number_of_actions) {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction>> res(number_of_actions);

  // allocate all of the memory for actions up front to amortize the cost.
  ActionClass* actions = 
    reinterpret_cast<ActionClass*>(new char[number_of_actions * sizeof(ActionClass)]);
  txn* txns = reinterpret_cast<txn*>(new char[number_of_actions * sizeof(TestTxn)]);

  // use placement new to initialize actions and assign them to unique_ptrs
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < number_of_actions; i++) {
    // construct the action using placement new from the memory allocated above.
    res[i].reset(new(&(actions[i])) ActionClass(new(&(txns[i])) TestTxn()));
  }
  return res;
}
```

Within main.cpp I just call the above functions multiple times, time it and return 0. The vector returned from the above function is destroyed in between loop iterations. As a result I get the following stack trace just before segfault:

```
#0  std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction, std::default_delete<IBatchAction> >::~unique_ptr (
    this=<optimized out>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:236
#1  std::_Destroy<std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction, std::default_delete<IBatchAction> > > (
    __pointer=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:93
#2  std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction, std::default_delete<IBatchAction> >*> (__last=<optimized out>, __first=0x7ffff7f06018)
    at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:103
#3  std::_Destroy<std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction, std::default_delete<IBatchAction> >*> (
    __last=<optimized out>, __first=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:126
#4  std::_Destroy<std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction, std::default_delete<IBatchAction> >*, std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction, std::default_delete<IBatchAction> > > (__last=0x7ffff7fc9510, 
    __first=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:151
#5  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction, std::default_delete<IBatchAction> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<IBatchAction, std::default_delete<IBatchAction> > > >::~vector (this=0x7fffffffd910, 
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:424
#6  time_workload_creation (exp_conf=...) at start_batch/main.cc:18
#7  0x000000000040320c in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>)
    at start_batch/main.cc:44
```

I'm new to the concept of placement new. The following is what I have used to write the above code:

1. [Can I use placement new to reset an object within a shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797825/can-i-use-placement-new-to-reset-an-object-within-a-shared-ptr) -- usage of reset to assign a new object created using placement new
2. [placement new on shared_ptr make seg fault when delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363544/placement-new-on-shared-ptr-make-seg-fault-when-delete) -- a very similar problem. The answers to this one did one help me at all :(

I'm likely doing something obviously wrong, but I can't figure it out. Help? If you need the actual code from main (simplified), here it is (actions.h contains the function I have discussed).

```
#include "actions.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

void time_workload_creation(unsigned int act_num) {
  std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time_start, time_end;
  std::vector<double> results;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    time_start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto workload = allocate_actions(act_num);
    time_end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    results.push_back(
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time_end - time_start).count());
  }

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::cout << i << "\t\t" <<  
      act_num << "\t\t" <<  
      results[i] << "\t\t" <<  
      act_num / results[i] << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  time_workload_creation(1000000);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled using: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Code after changing to use placement new:
>   [...]

This code has undefined behaviour. You create an array of `char` using `new[]` and then reset N `unique_ptr` objects which will try to delete N different `ActionClass` objects. How do you expect that to work? You need to use `delete[]` to free the array of char, not use N `delete` operations on chunks of the `char` array.

Similarly, each `ActionClass` will try to `delete` its `txn` object, but that's also totally undefined, because you didn't allocate N `txn` objects, you allocated another array of `char`.

That's not how memory allocation works. You can't allocate a big chunk and then deallocate pieces of it. (Well, you can, but only by writing your own custom (de)allocation functions, or allocator).

Comment: Well, he should at the very least use a custom deleter for the `unique_ptr` to avoid calling `delete` on each element.

Comment: @EvanTeran which would change the return type of the function (if that's an option there are much better ways to solve it). And nothing would delete the `char` array, so it it would leak the memory.

Comment: I agree with your assessment; I was just presenting options. After all, it is probably possible to deal with the memory leak, but likely it will be not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose my idea of allocation was wrong. Would you have any good pointer that I could use to read up on why "allocating a big chunk and deallocating small chunks within it" just does not work? On the whole there will be no memory leakage, right?

Comment: @Ebstein for the same reason that you can't do `void* p = malloc(3); free(2 + (char*)p); free(1+(char*)p); free(p);` If you allocate an array of `char` with `new[]` then you must deallocate the array (not pieces of it!) with `delete[]`. You can't just chop it up and return arbitrary pieces of it, how would the underlying `malloc` know what the hell you are trying to do, or which bits of memory you're still using?

Comment: _"On the whole there will be no memory leakage, right?"_ It's undefined behaviour, anything can happen including memory leaks of segfaults, or completely trashing the heap and corrupting the process' entire address space.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you! :-)